# Flux, Redshift and Night Color don't work (Ubuntu Budgie)

Tags: budgie

Help me, please. I can't work without flux. I tried everything. Flux does nothing (even when I press preview button), Night Color applet does nothing and Redshift gives "trying location provider 'geoclue2'" error

Comment: You might want to try latest redshift from `ppa:dobey/redshift-daily` which has many fixes. Also, are you running Budgie 11 that's built on Qt/Wayland, or the older Budgie that's using Xorg?

Comment: Hasn't Budgie's move to `qt` stalled? Or do you have a link to a stable release version of Budgie 11?

Answer (score 2):

If, for whatever reason, Flux, Redshift or the Night Color applet do not work for you, consider installing `sct` from the *universe repository* **provided you're on 18.04 or higher**. `sct` isn't available for 16.04 or older versions.

It's a small program and probably won't pull in many dependencies. You can try `apt install -s sct` to preview what will be installed: `-s` provides a simulation and doesn't need `sudo`.

If you do decide to try `sct`, `man sct` has

```
DESCRIPTION
       sct sets the screen's color temperature in a range from 1000 to 10000

OPTIONS
       temperature
              If passed a value in the correct range (see above) sct will set the current screen temperature to this value

       -h     If -h is passed sct will display usage information

       none   If no options are passed sct sets the color temperature to the default of 6500
```

So when you want a warmer screen, open a terminal and run `sct 3500` for example. And when you want to revert to normalcy, just run `sct`.

Comment: Using: `apt policy sct` returns: `N: Unable to locate package sct`. I've been digging through `sct` source code though and think I found the problem. Iniital release was July 2016 after Ubuntu 16.04 was published. I'm on 16.04 are you on 18.04?

Comment: Yes, I'm on 18.04. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ confirms that  `sct` isn't in 16.04. Sorry about that! I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Eyesome

I developed [Eyesome](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/eyesome) that runs 24/7 to:

- Control display brightness and gamma (night light, etc) for **three** monitors.
- Each morning it gets the sunrise and sunset times from the internet based on your city name.
- Brightness and gamma is gradually increased after sunrise
- Brightness and gamma is gradually decreased before sunset
- Sleeps ~ 12 hours daily and nightly unless resuming from suspend or monitors switched on/off

## Sample Configuration - General Tab

[image]

## Sample Configuration - Monitor 3 Tab

[image: eyesome configuration monitor 3.png]